# How to write Junit for main method which prints "Hello, World!" string to the console and uses Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, testing

I'm a beginner with Spring and have the following code:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("helloWorldService")

public class HelloWorldService {

    private String name = "Hello World";

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

/**
 * Hello class to start this Java application
 */

```
public class Hello {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Hello.class.getName());

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "applicationContext.xml");

        final HelloWorldService service = (HelloWorldService) context.getBean("helloWorldService");
        final String message = service.getName();
        Hello.LOGGER.info(message);

    }
}
```

How do I need to write a test? Since if I use this.log.getLog (), then the actual output in Junit is left empty for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the question is about how to verify that some value is actually written to the Log. If you are using Spring Boot, you can use OutputCapture to verify what has been written to the console. Un exemple is given in [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-output-capture-test-utility).

In general, however, your unit tests should allow to verify the actual result of some operation against the expected one. The method `getName` in `HelloWorldService` is a good candidate for such a test, since you can add Junit (or other framework) assertions that the returned value is equal to what you expect.